# how to implement tab layout using only one activity?

Tags: android

official android dev website says that:「You can implement your tab content in one of two ways: use the tabs to swap Views within the same Activity,.....」

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

i just wanna use tabs to swap views, no more than one activity.

could someone teach me how to do that?? is there any sample code?? thx ~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590340/android-tabs-mapview-activities-within-tabs/3695817#3695817) awhile ago about this.  Check out the responses.  One includes a rather detailed [tutorial](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=86).

Answer (score 0):

i've found this , 
http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/1.6/out/target/common/docs/offline-sdk/guide/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

this is a official example code , using one activity with 3 tabs~