# Android Render Google Map inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mapview

[image]

As shown above i have a Fragment Activity which renders two fragements. On the Map Fragment i want to implment and display a Map.

Since we need to extend MapActivity i am not sure how it can be done inside a fragment.

**Trying to implement Solution from** 
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/10739200/1737771)

```
package com.m7.nomad;

import android.app.LocalActivityManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Window;

public class MapsFragment extends SherlockFragment {
    private static final String KEY_STATE_BUNDLE = "localActivityManagerState";
    private LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager;

    protected LocalActivityManager getLocalActivityManager() {
        return mLocalActivityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle state = null;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            state = savedInstanceState.getBundle(KEY_STATE_BUNDLE);
        }

        mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(getActivity(), true);
        mLocalActivityManager.dispatchCreate(state);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // This is where you specify you activity class
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), GMapActivity.class);
        Window w = mLocalActivityManager.startActivity("tag", i);
        View currentView = w.getDecorView();
        currentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        currentView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        ((ViewGroup) currentView)
                .setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);
        return currentView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBundle(KEY_STATE_BUNDLE,
                mLocalActivityManager.saveInstanceState());
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mLocalActivityManager.dispatchResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mLocalActivityManager.dispatchPause(getActivity().isFinishing());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mLocalActivityManager.dispatchStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mLocalActivityManager.dispatchDestroy(getActivity().isFinishing());
    }

}
```

What should i specify for near

```
..............
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // This is where you specify you activity class
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), GMapActivity.class);
        Window w = mLocalActivityManager.startActivity("tag", i);

..................
```

Comment: you can refer [this](https://github.com/petedoyle/android-support-v4-googlemaps)

Comment: This may help you.. refer below link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109336/mapview-in-a-fragment-honeycomb

Comment: @YashdeepPatel i had a look at that. but i am not able to understand how to implement it. any tutorial on how it can be done ?

Comment: @hotveryspicy is there any tutorial or guide on how to implement that. may be some documentation ?

Comment: I had exactly this issue, and I solved it using user1414726's solution in the link that Yashdeep Patel posted just above. It was easy to do. The solution is right there. If you don't understand something in the solutions already provided then ask for specific help on what it is you don't understand.

Comment: @Trevor i tried to implement that solution but i dont understand this part Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), GMapActivity.class);
  Window w = mLocalActivityManager.startActivity("tag", i);

Comment: @Trevor i have pasted my code in the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the new [Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) that was just released.  It contains support for fragments (including the support library) and much more.

Answer (score 2):

[MapView in Fragment ( Android 4.0 or higher)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959072/mapview-in-fragment-ics) . have you look into this?.. and also this may help you ..https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Maps/NooYawkFragments

Comment: i tried that i got this 12-03 03:22:36.903: E/dalvikvm(12866): Could not find class 'com.google.android.maps.MapView', referenced from method com.m7.nomad.MapsFragment.onActivityCreated

Comment: am getting the following 12-03 04:07:03.723: E/AndroidRuntime(13715): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity. Here is the Code i am using - pastebin.com/De6gKG4f looks like i need to have a Map view some where i didnt understand why u have created NooYawk.java when its not being calling from any where