# Android Inflate Layout With its Own Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, layout, android-inflate

Good Day everyone.I have searched internet and hardly found that it can't be like that but i really can't believe.So i decided to ask here whether is it possible to inflate layout which will have its own activity i mean JAVA CLASS where i would type the code.So just for this case.Imagine we must have google maps on screen and as well as separate screen of list view people all nearby.So in that point we want to inflate the layout onto google maps view.But as i can logically think it will be horrible to write code all in one class by side of performance,so I'm looking for alternatives to inflating a layout,is somehow we can bring activity on main screen and don't lose that screen as well?This is all questions.Thank you very much beforehand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood you right, you want to have two layouts in one Activity?
You should use Fragments for it purpose. You can add as many as you want in one Activity, and manage them dynamically. You can find solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681660/android-render-google-map-inside-a-fragment). Also, look at [this](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/03/dual-mapfragment-of-google-maps-android.html) solution.

[image]