# SupportMapFragment getMap is null

Tags: android, supportmapfragment

I have a MapFragment in my XML:

```
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/mapFrag"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/map_topbar"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

In my **MapViewFragment** I have a

```
     GoogleMap gmap;
```

in `onCreate` I do the following:

```
FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
SupportMapFragment mf =(SupportMapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.mapFrag);
gmap = mf.getMap();
```

But I get a **NullPointerException**.

I've search and tried a lot of SO solutions but so far none have helped.

I've followed different tutorial:

http://android-er.blogspot.dk/2013/01/create-mapfragment-and-googlemap-using.html
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html#maps_fragment

Where they use the same technique.

The log:

```
03-04 13:40:49.468: E/AndroidRuntime(32388): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 13:40:49.468: E/AndroidRuntime(32388): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 13:40:49.468: E/AndroidRuntime(32388):    at dk.adaptmobile.koegeapp.MapViewFragment.onCreate(MapViewFragment.java:56)
03-04 13:40:49.468: E/AndroidRuntime(32388):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1477)
03-04 13:40:49.468: E/AndroidRuntime(32388):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:893)
03-04 13:40:49.468: E/AndroidRuntime(32388):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
03-04 13:40:49.468: E/AndroidRuntime(32388):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-04 13:40:49.468: E/AndroidRuntime(32388):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
03-04 13:40:49.468: E/AndroidRuntime(32388):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
03-04 13:40:49.468: E/AndroidRuntime(32388):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-04 13:40:49.468: E/AndroidRuntime(32388):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-04 13:40:49.468: E/AndroidRuntime(32388):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-04 13:40:49.468: E/AndroidRuntime(32388):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
03-04 13:40:49.468: E/AndroidRuntime(32388):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 13:40:49.468: E/AndroidRuntime(32388):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-04 13:40:49.468: E/AndroidRuntime(32388):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
03-04 13:40:49.468: E/AndroidRuntime(32388):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
03-04 13:40:49.468: E/AndroidRuntime(32388):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Where **line 56 is gmap = mf.getMap();**

Comment: can you post logcat error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to place a map inside of a fragment then I suggest you to use the `MapView` object in your layout instead of the `MapFragment`, here is a code that works for me:

The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the fragment itself:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment  {

private static final String TAG = MapFragment.class.getSimpleName();
private MapView mapView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_mapview, container, false);

    // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
    mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    return view;
}


@Override
public void onPause() {
    mapView.onPause();
    super.onPause();
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    mapView.onResume();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
}
}
```

Comment: It works, I can successfully getMap now. Only weird thing is that the map is empty, it is just white(no tiles or grid) which leads me to think it is not an API key problem. Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: @AntonGregersen, and why exactly do you think it's not an api key problem?

Comment: @EmilAdz because when I had the map in a fragment it worked fine and when I google the problem it seems like when people have an api key problem they have a grid, not a blank map as I do.

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959072/mapview-in-fragment-android-4-0-or-higher) it has to be in a MapActivity.

Answer (score 2):

Your XML does not match your Fragment code, you are creating a `SupportMapFragment` object when in your XML you have `MapFragment`:

Replace this:

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/mapFrag"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/map_topbar"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

with:

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/mapFrag"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/map_topbar"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Comment: this is related to `android:minSdkVersion`, for greater than 11 OP's code is true

Comment: As it happens minSdkVersion is 10 but your suggestion unfortunately didn't help. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

**XML**

```
<fragment
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

**JAVA File**

```
googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

This works for me if your class extends `Activity`